# Realm android difficult query

Tags: android, realm

I want to create some difficult query. For example I have a query like this:

```
  realm.where(Interval.class)
                                .equalTo("typeId", e.getTypeId())
                                .isNotEmpty("description")
                                .isNotNull("description")
                                .sort("start_time", Sort.DESCENDING)
                                .limit(showItems)
                                .findAll()
```

By this query I get only `showItems == 5` records from data base. But my firs a record can be empty or null(the field `description` for first record can be empty or null). I cant understand how i can add this condition to my query(firs a record can be empty or null)

**My question:** How I can create a query for conditions: first record can be an empty or null(first record can contains `description` empty or null) but another recodrs cant be empty or null